# Can I prompt a download file name using the HTML 'download' attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, download

I am using the `download` attribute to specify a file name to download data as a .csv file, using the folloowing code

```
  $(this).attr({
    'download': fileName,
    'href': csvData,
    'target': '_blank'
  });
```

This works perfectly, except that the file name is based on the URL from which the data is retrieved, so it can get very long and complex.

Is it possible to 'prompt' the user with the file name - IOW, when they click the download link, Windows Explorer (or OS-equivalent) displays the "Save As" prompt, with `fileName` as the defaulted value?

FWIW, I have tried using 'invalid' characters like a question-mark at the beginning of `fileName`, to no avail. I've also tried other values for the `target` attribute, but no dice there either.

Obviously I could add a prompt within my code to show the file name, and then allow the user to specify the name there, but if there is something obvious I've missed...

EDIT

As an example, to make it clear, here's a sample webpage with two `<A>` links to an image - one displays the image, and one downloads it:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.userlogos.org/files/logos/pek/stackoverflow.png">Link to image</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.userlogos.org/files/logos/pek/stackoverflow.png" download="stackoverflow.png">Download image</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The second one downloads the image directly, as "stackoverflow.png". I want to be able to bring up a Save As dialog, if that's possible, so the user can choose the name to save the image under. The same as if I right-click on an image and select "Save image as...". I realize that this may not be possible, since this is really happening in that instance between the browser and the OS, but I hoped that if, for instance, I specified `download=?stackoverflow.png"` then MAYBE it would prompt the name. But apparently not.

Comment: What are you placing this attribute on? A button or a link?

Comment: It's just a link. Nothing special. If I specify <a href="" ...download="abc.csv"> then when I click on the link, the data is downloaded (to my Downloads folder) as abc.csv. What I'd like is to be able to prompt the name (but default to abc.csv. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it appears that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the file cannot be set using any attribute on the link. However if you can modify the server's request to add the [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header, you can set a specific filename to the file that is downloaded regardless of the structure of the URL.

Specifically the header you need to set is:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourfilename.pdf"
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand (possibly because of my poorly worded question). I'm not going to downvote, but please see my edited question above, which might make it clearer